# Django On-Insert trigger

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a model in Django which I want to be automatically populated with values once another model has objects inserted.
This is the originator model **Question**:

```
class Question(models.Model):
question = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
description = models.TextField('description', default=False)
voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='+')
votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Question View:

```
class QuestionApiView(AuthenticatedAPIView):
"""
Lists all questions or creates a new question
"""

def post(self, request, format=None):

    vote_data = request.data
    vote_data["created_by"] = request.user.id

    data["created_by"]=request.user.id

    print(vote_data)
    print(vote_data["voters"])
    voter_data = vote_data["voters"]

    result, valid = QuestionHelper.createQuestion(vote_data)
```

Question Helper:

```
class QuestionHelper(object):
@classmethod
def createQuestion(klass, questiondata):
    """
    creates a question
    """
    createdQuestion = QuestionSerializer(data=questiondata)
    if createdQuestion.is_valid():
        createdQuestion.save()
        return createdQuestion.data, True
    return createdQuestion.errors, False
```

Question Serializer:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is my **Choice** model which I want the values **Yes**, **No** and **Abstain** added onto **choice_text** once a Question object is created:

```
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
choice_text = models.CharField("choice", max_length=250)
```

This way, each Choice will be linked to a Question using the question_id

Comment: Uh not sure I unserstand, maybe you want to use the `choices` keyword in your `choice_text` field?

Comment: I wan't insert default values under choice_text column

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using choice options:

**models.py**

```py
YES = 0
NO = 1
ABSTAIN = 2

CHOICE_OPTIONS = (
    (YES, 'yes'),
    (NO, 'no'),
    (ABSTAIN, 'abstain'),
)

class Question(models.Model):
    choice = models.PositiveIntegerField(..., choices = CHOICE_OPTIONS)
```

**views.py**

```py
from . import models

# update a choice instance:
question = models.Question.objects.get(id='<the id>')
question.choice = models.YES
question.save()
```

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the delayed response. Let me try it out and revert.